# How does Razor distinguish between uses of the @ sign?

Tags: razor

Given the two examples of Razor content:

```
<div>@emailAddress</div>
```

And

```
<div>cbehrens@emailAddress.com</div>
```

I would expect that the first would output the value of a variable called email address, and the second would print the literal text "cbehrens@emailAddress.com".

How does Razor distinguish between these two uses of the @ sign?

Comment: apparently `@@` is the escape symbol for @. So im guessing `@emailAddress` would display the variable value.
Not sure would the second would do, as i cant test right now, would likely print  cbehrens followed by the `@emailAddress.com` value. `cbehrens@@emailAddress.com` would work though

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking for the specifics of how the engine distinguishes between the two uses - what is the specific delimiter or condition that makes the parser choose rendering a variable versus rendering direct content?

Comment: Sorry, you said "I would expect" can you confirm that the output as expected. i.e `@email = my@email.com.` using `@email` prints `my@email.com` and `my@email.com` prints `my@email.com` and not `my@my@email.com` which is what i would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Razor starts off in HTML mode until it sees the first @ character, then

- treats everything following that as a C# expression
- when the Razor parser detects the end of the expression, it switches back to HTML

So the underlined parts will be treated as C# source code:

```
<div>@emailAddress</div>
      ============             

<div>cbehrens@emailAddress.com</div>
              ================
```

This isn't always what you want... `emailAddress` probably doesn't have a property named `com`.

To fix that, surround your C# expression with brackets:

```
<div>cbehrens@(emailAddress).com</div>
              ==============
```

The closing bracket indicates "end of expression" and the parser switches back to HTML mode.

---

If you actually want to output a `@` character, use `@@` instead:

```
<div>cbehrens@@emailAddress.com</div>
```

Comment: This does not appear to be the case - in my Razor code, the email address is identified properly and emitted as content.

Comment: Ok then - great. Sometimes you need brackets, and I guess that's what you were asking.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of hoping somebody knew how it worked under the hood, so I wouldn't have to go look in the source code.

Comment: One possible correction: "treats everything following that as a C# expression" this is only true for .cshtml files, while .vbhtml will interpret at VB.NET code. The question does not specify though I agree, C# is more common.

Comment: This article describes Razor Syntax and how to use the "@" symbol properly.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.0